# Python import from relative path error

Tags: python

I am trying to import from a relative path using sys.path.append

My directories look like that: 
/main 
--run.py 
/tools 
--tool.py

at `main.py` I'm having this code for importing `tool.py`: 
`sys.path.append("../tools/")` 
`from tool import myFunc`

but when I run the code,  get thin error: `ImportError: No module named tool`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I was running the code from the wrong directory, so I guess the context of the running environment couldn't find the directory `tools`

I was at the parent directory and ran the code like this `python main\run.py`
Then, the interpreter looked for tools at the parent directory of of the project.

So I `cd main` and ran the code `python run.py` and it worked (because it looked for the tools dir in the project directory)